# Export created CSV to specific folder on server

Tags: php

My script creates the csv and will save it to the folder that the script is in, however, I am having issues getting it to save anywhere else.

This saves the file to the same directory the below script resides in:

`$f = fopen('upload.csv', 'w');`

I have tries various methods to get it to save elsewhere to no avail, for example:

`$f = fopen('../CSV/upload.csv', 'w');`
which does nothing! As a matter of fact all iterations I have tried does nothing.

Here is the complete code which includes my second example at trying to get it to save to folder "CSV":

```
include_once 'dbConfig.php';

$query = $db->query("SELECT *
FROM Clients
WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                   AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
AND (Scheduled IS NULL OR Scheduled <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ORDER BY Last_Seen DESC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
   $delimiter = ",";
   $filename = "1-Year-6-Months-" . date('m-d-Y') . ".csv";

   $f = fopen('../CSV/upload.csv', 'w');

   // Set column headers
   $fields = array('Rep', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'PH Mobile', 'Date', 'Time', 'PH Mobile', 'PH Home', 'PH Work', 'Business_Name', 'Add1', 'Add2', 'City', 'State', 'Zip');
   fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

   
   // Output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
       $lineData = array($row['Rep'], $row['Name'], $row['Last_Name'], $row['Email'], $row['Date'], $row['Time'], $row['PH_Mobile'], $row['PH_Home'], $row['PH_Work'], $row['Business_Name'], $row['Add1'], $row['Add2'], $row['City'], $row['State'], $row['Zip']);
       fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
   }
   
   // Move back to beginning of file
   fseek($f, 0);
   
   // Set headers to download file rather than displayed
   header('Content-Type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
   
   //output all remaining data on a file pointer
   fpassthru($f);
}
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Sounds like your user, that is running the script, doesn't have access to any other folder. What OS are you using, is it run as a service or stand-alone PHP. What user is running the script?

Comment: Both ways use a relative path, depending on the _current working directory_, which can be influenced from the environment in which the code is run. Use `realpath()` to resolve a relative path - if the return is `false`, the path can't be resolved (eg. doesn't exist)

Comment: Oh, and a subfolder like "CSV" must exist... if won't be created by fopen if it doesn't...